# Data binding is not working when $scope value assigned inside then function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Can anybody help me to find out what i'm doing wrong in here. I'm calling a **$http service** to upload the .xlsx file inside then function i'm assigning response data to **$scope variable**  and trying to bind it in the html but binding is not happening. any suggestions will help greatly thanks in advance.

here is the code sample.

```
fileUpload.uploadFile(file)
     .then(function(response) {
          console.log('File Uploaded Successfully');
            if (response.status == 201) {
                if(response.data!=undefined) {
                    var _data = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                        $scope.batchUploadDetails = _data;
                        console.log($scope.batchUploadDetails);
                    }
                }
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.batchUploadDetails = {};
        console.log('File Uploading Failed!');
});
```

Html template

```
<div class="col-xs-12 no_pad borderAll padding20 margTop20 mb20" >

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 no_pad">
        <label class="col-xs-12 no_pad labelNew">Employee count</label><span
                    class="col-xs-12 no_pad">{{ batchUploadDetails.employeeCount }}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 no_pad">
        <label class="col-xs-12 no_pad labelNew">Company code</label><span
                    class="col-xs-12 no_pad">{{ batchUploadDetails.companyCode }}</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what $scope variable are you talking about? _data?

Comment: I'm talking about $scope.batchUploadDetails

Answer (score 0):

You can use $apply to trigger $digest cycle.

```
fileUpload.uploadFile(file)
     .then(function(response) {
          console.log('File Uploaded Successfully');
            if (response.status == 201) {
                if(response.data!=undefined) {
                    var _data = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                        $scope.batchUploadDetails = _data;
                        setTimeout(function (){ 
                           $scope.$apply();// you can use $timeout as well. Here I used settimeout to avoid $digest already in progress error
                      },0)
                        console.log($scope.batchUploadDetails);
                    }
                }
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.batchUploadDetails = {};
        console.log('File Uploading Failed!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your scope variable inside $apply for the changes to take effect.

You can also use $timeout service which will eventually call $apply service.